# Play html5 sound files with flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I would like to use a class `Track` to have a function `playsound()` and this should play the sound on a html template.

**This is my class** :

```
class Track:
def __init__(self, name, path):
    self.name = name
    self.path = path

def playsound(self):
    # does something
```

Now I know that I will need javascript and ajax as well probably. But I'm still new to the concept and I would like to see how I would go about achieving that. The sound file should play `onload` and should simply be invoked when you type:

```
songname = Track('name', 'music/filename.ogg')

@app.route('/playSong')
def playSong():
    return songname.play()
```

If there is no way this can be done in this way, or there is a much better way, I'd be happy to be enlightened. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you should put an <audio> HTML element in your template and go from there. Flask will only serve the rendered template, it can't play the sound directly.

Comment: Right, but how would I trigger a javascript function to use the string data from the python app. Is that possible?

Comment: You could make a URL in Flask that only returns the audio source (in your case "music/filename.ogg"). Then, from JavaScript, make an AJAX request to that URL, get the audio source, and use getElementById to get the <audio> tag, set its "src" attribute to the source you just got, then call its load() function to load the new audio. After that, calling play() on the <audio> object should make it autoplay.

Comment: This worked for me: https://paste.ubuntu.com/24573875/. Make sure to put your music file (.ogg should work fine) into the static folder, and your index.html into the template folder of your Flask app. Also, change the filename in flask to the name of your song. After that, it should work.

Comment: Thank you I got it working already, your second comment made it clear enough. <3

Answer (score 2):

You can keep the src of  in HTML as

```
  <audio controls>
   <source src="http://127.0.0.1:5000/a" type="audio/wav"/>
  </audio>
```

where http://127.0.0.1:5000/a is the url which send_file the audio

python code :

```
@app.route('/a')
def returnAudioFile():
    path_to_audio_file = pwd+"\\question_folder\\audio.wav" #audio from project dir
    return send_file(
       path_to_audio_file, 
       mimetype="audio/wav", 
       as_attachment=True, 
       attachment_filename="test.wav")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, this is a very old question and I don't really need this anymore 

Comment: Still useful for some :)